# How can I Disable "Add To Cart Button" in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, addtocart, enable-disable

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can set the product stock status to 'Out of Stock'

Comment: you want to hide from product page only or what?

Comment: Yes Dhiren you got it right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Your custom module you can create `view/frontend/layout/default.xml` with the below content.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../vendor/magento/framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <head>
    <css src="css/custom.css" />
  </head>
</page>
```

Create a file in `view/frontend/web/css/custom.css`

```
button.tocart{display:none;}
```

Note that this will hide add to cart button from the listing as well as the product view page.

Answer (score 1):

Free module [ProductAvailable](https://github.com/karliuka/m2.ProductAvailable) hides the 'add to cart' button from your site.